# Функция вызванная из коллбека не работает Angular 12

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

Всем привет. Сейчас пишу страницу авторизации и столкнулся с проблемой.
После выполнения запроса, если результат success, то пользователя должно редиректнуть. Вот как я это сделал:

После клика функция отправляет объект с данными и функцию коллбека.
[image: функция отправляет объект с данными и функцию коллбека]

После выполняется ajax запрос и вызывается функция:
[image: выполняется ajax запрос и вызывается функция коллбека]

Вот скриншот консоли с ошибкой:

[image: скриншот консоли с ошибкой]

Так понял, объект routre инкапсулированный ранее не виден в функции. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуй заменить стрелочную функцию в `setTimeout` на обычную `function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Решением стало передача самого роута
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и использование уже его в необходимой функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пробовал решение из комментариев. "Попробуй заменить стрелочную функцию в setTimeout на обычную function(){}" Возможно оно то же работает.